# Pandas looking for time as index and ignore date

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'va actually 2 dataframe :

1. First one contain some information with date/time
2. The second one contain other information with date/time

I need to combine the 2 dataframe by using nearest time as key (ignore date)

I need with a given time in the first dataframe to find the nearest time index (or value) in the second dataframe

I hope you understand

EDIT :

FROM CSV dataFrame 1 :

```
date;index
01/01/90 00:00:00;2
01/01/90 00:00:30;9
```

FROM CSV dataFrame 2 :

```
date;value
02/02/00 00:00:02;300
```

NEEDED :

```
date;value;index
02/02/00 00:00:02;300;2
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data with desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='nearest'`:

```
#new indexes with same dates, but different times
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print (df1)
                                   date  index
date                                          
2017-02-20 00:00:00 1990-01-01 00:00:00      2
2017-02-20 00:30:00 1990-01-01 00:00:30      9

print (df2)
                                   date  value
date                                          
2017-02-20 00:02:00 2000-02-02 00:00:02    300

df3 = df1.reindex(df2.index, method='nearest')
#add values from df2
df = pd.concat([df3.drop('date', axis=1), df2], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   index                date  value
0      2 2000-02-02 00:00:02    300
```

Comment: Will this work if i add 02/02/00 00:00:04;300 to the csv because it will be the index 2 either

Comment: Why did you omit %H in your index ?

Comment: Thanks but i got : ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing if i use %H :/

Comment: Then try  `df1 = df1.sort_index()`

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.